# I am unable to receive multiple textbox array data in php and insert to mysql

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

**The html HTML Form look like showing at this image preview.**
[The HTML Form is look like this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/onSfx.png)
**I have made this HTML Form made through jQuery function through below code.**

```
    function add_product_row(count = '')
{
    var html = '';
    html += '<span id="row'+count+'"><div class="row">';
    html += '<div class="col-md-8">';
    html += '<select name="product_id[]" id="product_id'+count+'" class="form-control selectpicker" data-live-search="true" required>';
    html += '<?php echo fill_food_list($connect); ?>';
    html += '</select><input type="hidden" name="hidden_product_id[]" id="hidden_product_id'+count+'" />';
    html += '</div>';
    html += '<div class="col-md-3">';
    html += '<input type="number" name="quantity[]" class="form-control" required />';
    html += '</div>';
    html += '<div class="col-md-1">';
    if(count == '')
    {
        html += '<button type="button" name="add_more" id="add_more" class="btn btn-success btn-xs">+</button>';
    }
    else
    {
        html += '<button type="button" name="remove" id="'+count+'" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs remove">-</button>';
    }
    html += '</div>';
    html += '</div></div><br /></span>';
    $('#span_product_details').append(html);

    $('.selectpicker').selectpicker();
}

var count = 0;

$(document).on('click', '#add_more', function(){
    count = count + 1;
    add_product_row(count);
});
$(document).on('click', '.remove', function(){
    var row_no = $(this).attr("id");
    $('#row'+row_no).remove();
});
```

Please help me receive data in a php page and insert in mysql database.

Comment: Is your form submitted via AJAX or in the classic way? What `print_r($_REQUEST)` shows?

Comment: Please show how you submit the code, and how you manage the POST in your backend

Comment: Yes @Jared, Backend is receiving $_POST and $_REQUEST. But i don't know how to receive array data in POST/REQUEST.

Comment: Please check the complete code on https://codepen.io/satyasmobile/pen/xxpOjqJ

Answer (score 0):

Thank You everyone, I got the solution with just using following code line.

```
$items_id = $_POST['product_id'];  
$food_items=implode(",", $items_id);
$quantity = $_POST['quantity'];  
$items_qty=implode(",", $quantity);
```